# why does React.js doesn't display my component separately in a new window?

Tags: reactjs, routes, frontend, components, jsx

I'm new to React.js, and my first project is my portfolio website.
So I have the index page render all the components, but I want to render the Resume component in a new window separately.
Here's the code :

```
    import {
  Navbar,
  Home,
  Projects,
  Aboutme,
  Contact,
  Footer,
  Resume,
} from "./imports";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div id="app">
        <Navbar />
        <Home />
        <Projects />
        <Aboutme />
        <Contact />
        <Footer />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/resume">
            <Resume />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add errors/screenshots of what you are not achieving with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also new to react.js but I think you need something like this:

```js
  <Router>
    <div id="app">
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Navbar />
          <Home />
          <Projects />
          <Aboutme />
          <Contact />
          <Footer /> 
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/resume">
            <Resume />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, I was trying too figure out how to include the rendered component under the "/" path, which is what you did, thanks a lot

Comment: @SoulaimaneELManioui glad, it helped.